# How do I create album thumbnails for music files

Tags: android

I learned that `MediaStore.Audio.Albums` contains album thumbnail URIs to music files I transferred onto my phone. I also learned that these thumbnails are located in a folder called `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/` Apparently, these thumbnails have been created automatically, but not every music file has a thumbnail.

So if the `MediaStore.Audio.Albums` URI value of the music file is `null`, is there a way to create a thumbnail in `/storage.../albumthumbs/` and then set a new URI value in MediaStore.Audio.Albums`?

Comment: In that way need to add default thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of resources related to my question

[How to delete media store meta data](http://www.sandersdenardi.com/querying-and-removing-media-from-android-mediastore/)

[How to embed album art in mp3 files](http://www.richardfarrar.com/embedding-album-art-in-mp3-files/)

[How to get and set (change) ID3 tag (metadata) of audio files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707572/how-to-get-and-set-change-id3-tag-metadata-of-audio-files)