# Android: Editing ID3 tag of audio file corrupts file

Tags: android

I am trying to edit the metadata of audio files in my android app. After googling for some time I found [MyID3 library](http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/) to be the way to go.

This is my code.

```
public class TagEditor {

    public static void changeTag(String pathdata) {

        File src = new File(pathdata);
        MusicMetadataSet src_set = null;
        try {
            src_set = new MyID3().read(src);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } // read metadata

        if (src_set == null) // perhaps no metadata
        {
            Log.i("NULL", "NULL");
        } else {
            try {
                IMusicMetadata metadata = src_set.getSimplified();
                String artist = metadata.getArtist();
                String album = metadata.getAlbum();
                String song_title = metadata.getSongTitle();
                Number track_number = metadata.getTrackNumber();
                Log.i("artist", artist);
                Log.i("album", album);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            File dst = new File(pathdata);
            MusicMetadata meta = new MusicMetadata("name");
            meta.setSongTitle("Varun");
//            meta.setArtist("CS");
            try {
                new MyID3().update(src, src_set, meta);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ID3WriteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  // write updated metadata
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that changing the tags through this code doesn't have any effect on the tags in my music files. Instead the file gets corrupted and becomes unplayable.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707572/how-to-get-and-set-change-id3-tag-metadata-of-audio-files/9770646#comment58076618_9770646) answer and in the comments some people have raised a similar issue but no solution is presented to the problem. Seems that it works for others. Can someone please help me !!

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but your could use JAudioTagger instead... http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/index.jsp

Comment: @DanGravell Thanks for the suggestion, will give it a try.